BLE: Automation IO service (0x1815) and Number Of Digitals (0x2909) descriptor
I am considering an Automation IO BLE interface to broadcast various analog and digital signal values to a remote monitoring device. This profile seems to fit the bill in terms of the datatypes I need.
Is the purpose of the Number of Digitals (0x2909) descriptor an indication to the central node as to just how many valid digital elements are contained within the peripheral's Digital characteristic payload?

Questions on Stack Overflow must ask one thing only; please edit your question to focus on one question, instead of two.
